# Can I have dynamic variables in DSC File resource

Tags: powershell, runtime, dsc

How can I get a Desired State Configuration's File Resource to determine it's $DestinationPath at runtime?
This appears to be set only when the mof file is generated.

My  script below shows what I am trying to do. I know why it doesn't work, I can't find how to make it work.

The script looks at the PSModulePath variable on the target computer and extracts a single path from the variable. I want to pass this path to a File Resource in the script to install some custom Powershell modules in that path.

I use the variable $LocalInstallPath but that doesn't work because it is set in the File resource when the mof file is created. Tried setting in as an environment variable instead, but same problem.

Is there a way to do this?

```
Configuration InstallCustomPowershellModules
{
    param($MachineName)

    Node $MachineName
    {
        $CustomModuleSource = '\\fileserver\modules\Module1'

        Script GetLocalPath
        {
            SetScript = { 
                $FullPath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", "Machine")
                $SplitPath = $FullPath -split ";"
                foreach ($ShortPath in $SplitPath)
                {
                    $result = Select-String -Pattern 'system32' -InputObject $ShortPath
                    if($result -ne $null)
                    {
                        break
                    }
                }
                $LocalInstallPath = $ShortPath
            }

            TestScript = { $false }
            GetScript  = { $true }         
        }


       File InstallCustomModule
        {
           Ensure = 'Present'
           Type = 'Directory'
           SourcePath = $CustomModuleSource
           DestinationPath = $LocalInstallPath
           Force = $true
           Recurse = $true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We do not (yet) support expanding environment variables at runtime. Therefore  your only option is to use a Script resource to do the copying

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get `$LocalInstallPath` without separate script block

```
$LocalInstallPath = $env:PSModulePath.Split(';')|?{$_ -like '*system32*'} | select -First 1
```

So

```
File InstallCustomModule
        {
           Ensure = 'Present'
           Type = 'Directory'
           SourcePath = $CustomModuleSource
           DestinationPath = $env:PSModulePath.Split(';')|?{$_ -like '*system32*'} | select -First 1
           Force = $true
           Recurse = $true
        }
```

p.s. I didn't test this code in exact your scenario, hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks for that. The syntax of the command works fine, and I will use it. Unfortunately it is still expanded at compile time of the mof file, i.e. on the machine I create the script, not the machines where it will run. Whilst it is most likely this path will be the same everywhere, that is not guaranteed, and not future prooffed, so I was hoping to get the as expansion of $DestinationPath at runtime, rather than compile time.

Comment: The only workaround i figured out is to copy file inside script block like `SetScript = {$LocalInstallPath = $env:PSModulePath.Split(';')|?{$_ -like '*system32*'} | select -First 1; cp $CustomModuleSource $LocalInstallPath}`

Comment: That was going to be my work-around too. What I am now trialling now is to make my own dedicated directory and adding it to the PSModulePath, then use the File resource to take care of the transfer. This would work well as we will develop a number of modules.